# Dojo: set store for template filteringselect

Tags: templates, select, dojo, store

in order to get familiar with dojo I'm working on a test project which consists of the following components:

- data grid (created declaratively), filled with JSON data; clicking on a line will open a dialog containing a form (works)
- form (created from template), with several input fields, filled with data from the grid store (works)
- FilteringSelect (part of form) (doesn't work, no content)

The FilteringSelect contains dynamic data. In order to keep data traffic low, I thought it wise to get this data when the whole page is loaded and to pass it into the template initialization function.

In fact, I don't really know how to assign the store to the FilteringSelect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code. I shorten it to the what I consider relevant parts so that it's easier to understand.

Grid Part:

```
    var data_list = fetchPaymentProposalList.fetch();

    /*create a new grid*/
    var grid = new DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout
    });

        // store for FilteringSelect
    var beneficiaryList = FetchBeneficiaryList.fetch();
    var beneficiaryListStore = new Memory({
        identifier : "id",
        data : beneficiaryList
    });

    return   {
            // function to create dialog with form
        instantiate:
            function(idAppendTo)   {
                /*append the new grid to the div*/
                grid.placeAt(idAppendTo);

                /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
                grid.startup();
                grid.resize();

                dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, function(evt)   {
                    var rowItem = this.getItem(evt.rowIndex);
                    var itemID = rowItem.id[0];
                    var store = this.store;


                    var paymentProposalForm = new TmpPaymentProposalForm();
                    paymentProposalForm._init(store.getValue(rowItem, "..."), ..., beneficiaryListStore);
                });
        }
    };
```

The beneficiarylist comes as something like this:

```
return { 12: { id : 1, name : "ABC" }};
```

The FilteringSelect in the template looks like this:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" name="recipient" id="recipient" value="" data-dojo-props="" data-dojo-attach-point="recipientNode" />
```

Template Init Code looks like this:

```
_init: function(..., beneficiaryListStore)   {
            this.recipientNode.set("labelAttr", "name");
            this.recipientNode.set("searchAttr", "name");
            // here should come the store assignment, I guess???

            var dia = new Dialog({
                content: this,
                title: "ER" + incoming_invoice,
                style: "width: 600px; height: 400px;"
            });
            dia.connect(dia, "hide", function(e){
                dijit.byId(dia.attr("id")).destroyRecursive(); 
            });
            dia.show();
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you just add `this.recipientNode.set("store", beneficiaryListStore);` ?

Comment: FilteringSelect remains empty.
I'm wondering if my store might be wrongly set up...

Comment: Double check that there is data in the store: `beneficiaryListStore.query().forEach(console.log);` (and watch the console to see if it outputs the data you expect).

Comment: It seems like this is where the problem is. I don't get any output, which is not what I expect.
So I'll have another look at my store then....

Thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: So, it was indeed the structure of my store which was faulty.

Comment: Here's my solution:
`var beneficiaryList = FetchBeneficiaryList.fetch();
     var beneficiaryData = {
      identifier : "id",
      items : []
     };
     for(var key in beneficiaryList)
     {
      if(beneficiaryList.hasOwnProperty(key))
      {
       beneficiaryData.items.push(lang.mixin({ id: key }, beneficiaryList[key]));
      }
     }
     var beneficiaryListStore = new Memory({
      identifier : "id",
      data : beneficiaryData
     });`

That did the trick

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested, here's my solution:

```
var beneficiaryList = FetchBeneficiaryList.fetch();
    var beneficiaryData = {
        identifier : "id",
        items : []
    };
    for(var key in beneficiaryList)
    {
        if(beneficiaryList.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            beneficiaryData.items.push(lang.mixin({ id: key }, beneficiaryList[key]));
        }
    }
    var beneficiaryListStore = new Memory({
        identifier : "id",
        data : beneficiaryData
    });
```

That did the trick

Comment: Ah, should have spotted that in your question. +1 for posting your solution. You can probably reduce the number of lines a little bit too, if you want to. Create the store first (no parameters necessary, since "id" is the default identifier), then `beneficiaryListStore.add(lang.mixin....` inside the loop.